# Does Unobtrusive validation in .NET 4.5 require jquery.validate?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on ASP.NET web forms project. I am confused as far as what jQuery I need to have in the Script of the page(s) for the .NET 4.5 unobtrusive validation.  In some articles I read that I need to have jquery and in some others it says that I need to have jquery.validate.  So do I need both of these .js libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery.validate.js` relies on `jquery.js`, so you need both included. Also, ensure that you reference `jquery.js` before validate otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: Rory,  thank you very much.  Strange thing was that this morning I was testing a page and only included jquery.js (no jquery.validate.js) and the test worked. But I will add jquery.validate.js; never hurts to have it.

Comment: @Hidalgo it could be you had a cached version of the page which included the necessary js. Either way, glad to help.

Comment: Rory, if you don't mind, another question. I am testing this unobtrusive validation in IE 10. Do you know if it will also work in IE 8 and IE 9 (I am not even asking about IE 6&7 :))?

Comment: validate should, however if you're using jquery >1.9 then support for older browsers was dropped. You may need to downgrade jQ if you need support for them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - That's incorrect.  If you're using jQuery 2.0 or greater it drops support for older browsers.  jQuerey 1.10 and jQuery 1.11 work just fine in older browsers (those are greater than 1.9)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch you're correct. I got the version progression mixed up.